# unable to use variable of one function to another function in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, tkinter-layout

I am trying to create the GUI, I am unable to use the value of a variable in one function on the other function in tkinter

But, in normal functions, when we declare the variable as global, it is accessible.

Here is my code,

```
from tkinter import *
global chosen_option
root = Tk()
root.title("Drop-down boxes for option selections.")

var = StringVar(root)
var.set("drop down menu button")

def grab_and_assign(event):
    grab_and_assign.var = var.get()
    label_chosen_variable= Label(root, text=chosen_option)
    label_chosen_variable.grid(row=1, column=2)
    print(chosen_option)

def pri():
    print(grab_and_assign.chosen_option)

drop_menu = OptionMenu(root, var,  "one", "two", "three", "four", "meerkat", "12345", "6789", command=grab_and_assign)
drop_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)

label_left=Label(root, text="chosen variable= ")
label_left.grid(row=1, column=0)
pri()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, for the specific code?

Comment: Please post any errors you're getting!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: there are many things wrong with your code. e.g. calling pri() directly and not via binding when the mainloop (interactive behaviour management of your GUI) is called afterwards. grab_and_assign.chosen_option is a function, not an object. chosen_object is never  assigned.

Comment: all variables created outside functions are global so they don't need `global`. You have to use `global` INSIDE function to inform function that it has to use external/global variable instead of creating local one.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

First: `mainloop()` starts window so your `pri()` is executed before you see window - so before you could selecte anything. I add `pri` to button so you can also see how it works after selecting option.

Second: all variables create outside functions/classes are global and they don't need keyword `global`. You have to use `global` inside function to inform function that when you will assign value using `=` then you what to use external/global variable instead of creating local one.

In code I have global variable `normal_var` and I use `global normal_var` inside `grab_and_assign` to inform function to assign value to global variable and not to create local variable in line

```
 normal_var = var.get()
```

I don't have to use `global` inside `pri()` because I only get value from variable `nromal_var` and don't use `=` to assign new value

I don't have to use `global` to assign new value for:

- `var` because it uses `set()` instead of `=`.
- `label_selected["text"]` because it assign value to key in dictionary.

But I would have to use `global` for `label_selected` if I would like to assign new `Label` inside function - ie. `label_selected = tk.Label(..)`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def grab_and_assign(event):
    global normal_var

    normal_var = var.get()

    label_selected["text"] = var.get()

def pri():
    print('normal_var:', normal_var)
    print('var.get():', var.get())
    print('---')

# --- main ---

# global variable
normal_var = "- empty -"

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Drop-down boxes for option selections.")

# it is global variable
var = tk.StringVar(root)
var.set("drop down menu button")

drop_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, var,  "one", "two", "three", "four", "meerkat", "12345", "6789", command=grab_and_assign)
drop_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)

label_left = tk.Label(root, text="chosen variable = ")
label_left.grid(row=1, column=0)

# create it only once
label_selected = tk.Label(root, text="?")
label_selected.grid(row=1, column=1)

# execute `pri` after button press
b = tk.Button(root, text='PRI', command=pri)
b.grid(row=2, column=0)

# execute `pri` before window starts
pri()

root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: `Label` has `textvariable=` and you can assign `var` which you use in `OptionMenu` and then it will automatically display selected value

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar(root)
var.set("drop down menu button")

label_selected = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var)
label_selected.pack()

drop_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, var,  "one", "two", "three", "four", "meerkat", "12345", "6789")
drop_menu.pack()

root.mainloop()
```